# Related products as a dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, products, related-products

Natively I can see its possible to have related products block on a product page but is it possible to not have it as a block but to just have a simple dropdowns based on categories.

For example if I am buying a computer I would like to have 3 dropdowns, 1 for screens, 1 for software and 1 for printers.

Each dropdown would contain related products for the revlant category

Answer (score 0):

Navtively you can't have multiple related products seperated into categories.

However if you wan't to use nativ functionality, you could use the bundle product feature in Magento, add the main product as an option, with only that, preselected and with no option to deselect, and then add the products you want as options for the bundle.

Comment: Unfortunately bundles would not work though as the main product (in this case the computer) as it is a configurable product within its self